# Outlook 365 - sound if internal email arrives only

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

***Requirement :*** Play sound if email is received addressed to me (To or CC) from any email that ends with @something.com only.

Currently I have a rule that plays a sound if an email is received where I am in the To or CC address. This works for all emails send to me or where I am copied.

The sound should only play if the email is an internal email. My train of thought is to use the Rules feature to filter based on my companies site extension.

I cannot use VBA. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an inbox rule looks like below:
[image]

Check above and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanx ! cant believe I missed that rule. It works 100%

Comment: Glad to hear that the solution works for you, you could mark the solution as best answer if someone encounters the same issue, they could find the solution quickly :)